# Number of users that logged in the past day

Tags: python, mysql, django, session

I am building a python script that connects to a site's mysql database through the MySQLdb library. The site is based on django.
I want to get the number of users that logged on the site in the past 24 hours, maybe using the django sessions table. How can I do this using only python and mysql?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you can't count it precisely before you can identify the visiting user whose session has not expired.

Comment: I want something approximate, not precisely.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.contrib.auth import User

yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
users = User.objects.filter(last_login = yesterday)
```

Haven't tried this, but I think this should work

Comment: Again, same problem. If a user's session hasn't expired and he visits the site, the last_login field won't be updated. And I mentioned I only want to use python and mysqldb for this script. No django.

Comment: Why should the login_field be updated? The session is still active, so there is no login required. If you are looking for, how many users surfed on your site in 24h, you could write a middleware which stores the user and the last time he made a request in the DB - thus using django (which is python and has a nice ORM for SQL).